# GNU Health installation error , when creatting database

Tags: gnu, failed-installation

I am trying to install the GNU Health in ubuntu 12.04,when I am trying to create the database in my localhost it says "Could not connect to server"

Answer (score 1):

Follow instructions here: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GNU_Health/Installation

I suggest you join the GNU health mailing list and post your questions to the list, you have better chances of getting answers: https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/health